# How can I add navigation arrows on the “JQuery Photo Slider with Semi Transparent Caption”?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using the "JQuery Photo Slider with Semi Transparent Caption" from queness.com (http://www.queness.com/resources/html/slideshow/jquery-slideshow.html) and I love it.

The only bit missing is navigation buttons. I have modified the original HTML and added navigation buttons, but don't know how to instantiate/invoke the navigation:

```
 <div style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible; width: 550px; height: 350px;">



<div id="slider-container">

    <ul class="slideshow">

        @foreach ($images as $image)



            <li class="show"><a href="/link/{{ $image->id }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ $image->image_src }}" width="550" height="350" title="Title" alt="Desc"/></a></li>

         @endforeach



    </ul>



</div>





<div id="navigation">

                        <img style="opacity: 0;" id="prev" class="prev-button" src="prev.png" alt="Previous">

            <img style="opacity: 0;" id="next" class="next-button" src="next.png" alt="Next">

                                    <img style="opacity: 0; margin-left: -17px; display: none;" id="play" class="play-button" src="play.png" alt="Play">

            <img style="opacity: 0; margin-left: -17px; display: none;" id="pause" class="pause-button" src="pause.png" alt="Pause">

</div>



</div>
```

I ideally I need navigation shown on hover, like on this page: http://airmaster.co.ke/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you need to do is set up a few click handlers for your navigation buttons. I'm not sure whether you also want to implement the play/pause button functionality from the example, since it is not mentioned in your question.

So, to get started, since your next and previous navigation buttons are actually images and you have given them ids, we can set up the click handlers using jQuery as follows:

```
$('#prev').click(function(){
    // Handle click here
})

$('#next').click(function(){
    // Handle click here
})
```

Now that the click handlers are set up, we need to implement the actual navigation. According to this link (http://www.queness.com/post/152/simple-jquery-image-slide-show-with-semi-transparent-caption) the navigation is implemented as follows:

```
//if no li has the show class, grab the first image
var current = ($('ul.slideshow li.show')?  $('ul.slideshow li.show') : $('ul.slideshow li:first'));

$('#prev').click(function(){
     //Get previous image, if it reached the beginning of the slideshow, rotate it back to the last image
    var prev = (current.prev().length) ? current.prev() : $('ul.slideshow li:last');

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    prev.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
        .removeClass('show');
});

$('#next').click(function(){
    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = (current.next().length) ? current.next() : $('ul.slideshow li:first');

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
        .removeClass('show');
});
```

Also, you should remove the class "show" from this list item:

```
<li class="show"><a href="/link/{{ $image->id }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ $image->image_src }}" width="550" height="350" title="Title" alt="Desc"/></a></li>
```

So it should be:

```
<li><a href="/link/{{ $image->id }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ $image->image_src }}" width="550" height="350" title="Title" alt="Desc"/></a></li>
```

Because that loop is effectively giving every li a class of "show," which will break your code.

This, in theory, should get your code working properly. However, since you haven't provided enough code or a JSFiddle I can't make a working example for you.

Refer to the following link (mentioned above) to learn more about how the sideshow is implemented in code:

http://www.queness.com/post/152/simple-jquery-image-slide-show-with-semi-transparent-caption

**EDIT**

Also I forgot to add how to show your navigation buttons on hover. This is what you should add:

```
$('#navigation').hover(function(){
    // Code for when mouse enters

    // Animate opacity to 1 (fully visible) in 200 ms
    $('#next').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
    $('#prev').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200)
},function(){
    // Code for when mouse leaves

    // Animate opacity to 0 (invisible) in 200 ms
    $('#next').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
    $('#prev').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200)
});
```

Comment: I have changed code as advised but still can't get navigation to show up. Here is JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9spysuzd/

Comment: The code works just fine, you just forgot to attach a jQuery library to your JSFiddle and mimic the code in the body of your HTML as opposed to onLoad. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9spysuzd/1/. Also, you have many CSS errors that you need to fix before it works as you wish it to. Additionally, you will have to wait about 5-10 seconds for the fiddle to work properly due to it attempting and failing to load images. Note: your navigation appears at the bottom left of the fiddle, on hover.

Comment: I got the navigation showing, though I had to change `hover` from `$('#navigation').hover` to `$('#slider-container').hover`. The only remaining hitch is transition when one clicks `next` or `previous`. There's an overlap between slides and the image showing doesn't match the caption. At some point the caption stops showing altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with this slider, nor do I know much about JQuery, but I do want to try to help. Have you considered Slick Slider? It's quite easy, has 1 page (no more, no less) of tutorial and works great. You can find it here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. It does what you need, and is also free. If you want to keep your current slider, I'm afraid I can't help you. Good luck!